# Uninstall Grub without disk?

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, grub

I had Windows 10 dual booted with Ubuntu, so I deleted a partition which I was sure Ubuntu was on from Disk Management. I then extended the Windows 10 Partition to fill in the space that the old partition took up. Now when I boot up my laptop, it goes to grub. I can still get to Windows 10, it just takes longer and is a process. My goal is to have Windows only and for it to start up normally, as if I never installed Ubuntu. I also don't have a Windows 10 disk or plan on reinstalling windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Grub has been installed to your boot loader.  You'll need to boot into a windows recovery disk or partition to restore the windows boot loader.

Comment: So that's the only way? Everywhere I look online says that